# Github Pages Publishing homepage URL not changing

Tags: git, github, deployment, web-deployment, github-pages

I am trying to deploy my website using Github pages and for some reason the correct publishing URL isn't reflected. In my package.json, I have my homepage as : **"https://****my-username**.github.io**/**repo-name**"** and then when I pushed my changes to my master branch and ran npm run deploy my site will always gets published to **https://**myname.com**/**repo-name****.

I have tried renaming my repository to my username.github.io but apparently it already exists ( as a result, I'm keeping my repository name as it is). I've cleared my cache in chrome, deleted my gh-pages branch and installed gh-pages again to create the branch again, and configured my github pages site to be built from my gh-pages branch. If it also helps, I've been following this Youtube tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6Rto09ElUuY&t=478s.

I also need my username.github.io to work because I need it for making changes to my custom domain's DNS (I plan on using a custom domain but want to ensure my username.github.io/repo URL works first). I'm lost on ideas as I have tried different things and any help would be appreciated!

[Here is a screenshot of my GH pages' settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rHgdV.png)

Comment: Can you please provide your Github Pages link?

Comment: yes. It's this: http://arianahwang.com/latin-shui-artist-site/

Comment: It is not opening, I think it would be better if you give the github repository link instead of Github pages link.

Comment: Ok got it. This is my repo link: https://github.com/Ahwan0717/latin-shui-artist-site

Comment: I have added an answer, try it. And as per I know, Github redirects you repository link [http://ahwan0717.github.io](http://ahwan0717.github.io/) to [http://arianahwang.com](http://arianahwang.com) .

Answer (score 0):

The domain "[arianahwang.com](http://arianahwang.com)" is not purchased, and you just have saved it as your custom domain. To host the site with Github Pages, you at first need to purchase the domain. And if you directly want to host with github pages, then:

- Go to settings of the repository,
- Erase the custom domain(i.e.,[arianahwang.com](http://arianahwang.com)), and save it.
- Now you can see your Github site url displayed over there.